# Which boolean algebras are isomorphic to the algebra of definable sets for some structure with specific parameters?

Tags: model-theory, boolean-algebra

Every boolean algebra is the algebra of clopen sets of some topological space, by [Stone's representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_representation_theorem_for_Boolean_algebras).

Not every boolean algebra is isomorphic to the powerset algebra of some set, though. Although, every finite boolean algebra is isomorphic to a powerset algebra. I think the powerset algebras are the algebras of definable sets when we restrict ourselves to structures with an empty signature.

Is there a nice way to characterize which boolean algebras you can hit by considering the algebras of definable sets in a given structure? I'm curious about the class consisting of the boolean algebra for each $(M, A)$ where $M$ is a first-order structure is $A \subset M$ is a set of parameters.

Comment: There is no point mentioning a parameter set $A$ if it is fixed: definable subsets of $M$ with parameters in $A$ are the same as parameter-free definable subsets of $M$ where you enlarge the language with a constant for each element of $A$.

Comment: It's not true that power set algebras are the algebras of definable sets with an empty signature (and a fixed set of parameters).  The definable subsets of $M$ with parameters in $A$ with respect to the empty signature are the sets that are either a finite subset of $A$ or the complement of such a set.  Up to isomorphism, this gives the algebras that consist of all the finite or cofinite subset of some set, not the full power set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every Boolean algebra is an algebra of definable sets.  More strongly, given any set $X$ and any subalgebra $B\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$, there is a first-order structure on $X$ whose algebra of definable subsets (without parameters) is $B$.  To do this, just make a unary relation for each element of $B$ which is true on that subset of $X$.  Clearly then each element of $B$ is definable.  For the converse, any formula can involve only finitely many of the relations, and so it suffices to consider the case where $B$ is finitely generated and hence finite.  In that case, $B$ just consists of the unions of elements of some finite partition of $X$.  Any two elements of the same block of the partition are indistinguishable with respect to all the unary relations, and so any definable subset must be a union of blocks, and thus an element of $B$.